# Data connection between two modems

Tags: at-command, modem, satellite

I have a sat modem and a 56k modem. I am unable to establish a data connection between them. When I use the sat modem to make a data call to the 56k modem the hyperterminal on the sat modem says CONNECTED 9600 and then a NO CARRIER after 10 seconds. Nothing is displayed in the 56k side hyperterminal except that it shows that it is ringing. When I check the reason why it says that there is a HANDSHAKE FAILURE. The last setting I found was to set the bps to 1200 and use AT+MS=V22 for the 56k modem. Now what happens is that it fails on the first call. Same Connected , No carrier message. But when I call again, the hyperterminal on both side shows connected but the 56k side would display random characters then no carrier after printing it out. Any suggestions on what S-registers to explore or what might be causing a handshake failure between modems.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.